# Restarting a JavaScript websocket when the server restarts - why does this code restart multiple websockets?

Tags: javascript, websocket, fastapi

I'm trying to get a **websocket connection** to **automatically restart** after it has been closed by the server.

My example code works, when I open the page in a browser at "http://127.0.0.1:5082/".
The websocket counter counts up, the debug text "message" is displayed.

When I turn off the server, the debug message "close" appears, then "start/close" alternate.

When I turn the server on again, there are dozens of websockets running and the debug message quickly changes between "message" and "close"

How do I make sure that **only one** websocket connection is alive at a time?

Minimal example, using Python's FastAPI as a server:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Websocket test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    OK - wait for websocket
</div>
<hr noshade>
<div id="debug">
    Some debug text here
</div>

<script>

    var debug_container = document.getElementById("debug")
    debug_container.innerHTML = "Debug: Javascript is running"

    function my_websocket() {
        debug_container.innerHTML = "starting"
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5082/ws")

        ws.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
            debug_container.innerHTML = "message"
            var container = document.getElementById("container")
            container.innerHTML = event.data
        })
        ws.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
            debug_container.innerHTML = "open"
        })
        ws.addEventListener('close', function (event) {
            debug_container.innerHTML = "close";
            setInterval(my_websocket, 5000);
        })
        ws.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
            debug_container.innerHTML = "error"
        })
    }

    my_websocket()

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The websocket is served by a Python FastAPI server

```
import uvicorn
import websockets
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from pathlib import Path
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
def index():
    return HTMLResponse(Path("index.html").read_text())


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    cnt = 1
    while True:
        cnt += 1
        try:
            await websocket.send_text(f"{cnt}")
        except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK:
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(0.25)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app=app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5082)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the client establishes multiple websocket connections is due to the following code:

```
ws.addEventListener('close', function (event) {
    debug_container.innerHTML = "close";
    setInterval(my_websocket, 5000);
})
```

Using setInterval causes it to create a new websocket connection every 5 seconds. I think you meant to use setTimeout() instead.

Comment: This has improved the situation, but I still get multiple websockets running when I turn the server off and turn it on again later.

Comment: This problem was caused my a second on settimeout for "error", after I removed that, it works. thanks